# How to find a bit pattern along the diagonals of a matrix in Python

Tags: python, design-patterns, matrix

I have a 2D matrix (`M`) of size `n x n` with binary elements. I want to scan the diagonals of this matrix to filter out bit patterns, say bit pattern `111` (length of bit pattern is user defined).

Let me explain more of it to make my problem clear. The filtering criteria is such that if

1. `M(i, j) == 1` and two (in this case) of its adjacent neighbours `M(i-1, j-1)` and `M(i+1, j+1)` are also `1` then `M(i,j)` is kept `1` otherwise it is changed to bit `0`.
2. Or, `M(i,j) ==1` and it has at least two preceding `1`s or two following `1`s in the same diagonal then even if condition first is not true still `M(i,j)` should be kept `1`.

I am new to the python and struggling with it so any help/suggestions to solve this issue would be most welcome…

Comment: Can you show some code you have written and the matrix you want to parse?

Answer (score 0):

I'll help get you started then you can make an attempt and lets see where you are at.

```
matrix = [[0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]]

for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
        print(matrix[i][j])
```

Now you've parsed your matrix, try figuring out the comparison and then the substitution should be easy.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. So, if I do it like below then I can get hold of main diagonal elements. for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
        if (i==j):
           print(matrix[i][j])

Comment: In addition to main diagonal scanning, how can I get control to other diagonals parallel to main diagonals?

Answer (score 0):

It may help if you see if visually, try printing your results

```
matrix = [[0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0]]

for i in range(len(matrix)):
    line = ''
    for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
        line += str(matrix[i][j]) + " "
    print(line)

diagonal = ''
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
        if i == j:
            diagonal += str(matrix[i][j]) + ' '

print('Diagonal: ' + diagonal)
```

Output:

```
0 1 0 1 
1 1 1 1 
0 1 1 0 
1 0 1 0 
Diagonal: 0 1 1 0
```

Now try some experimenting and see if you can get the parallel diagonals.